# Como copiar valores de um vetor para outro de forma rápida?

Tags: c, array, otimização

Estou fazendo uma questão que o número de elementos no vetor estão em 10^6 e só queria copiar determinados elemento para ele só que fiz da forma normal, mas comum, há outra possibilidade se fazer a cópia mais rápida?

```
for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
{
    if(primo(vetor[i]))
    {
       aux[cont] = vetor[i];
       cont++;
    }
}
```

Algoritmo para encontrar o número primo

```
int primo(int num)
{
  int pri = 1, i, raiz = sqrt(num);
  if(num == 2)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  if (num == 1 || num == 0 || num % 2 == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  for(i = 3; i <= raiz; i += 2)
  {
     if(num % i == 0)
     {
         pri = 0;
         break;
     }
  }
   return pri;
}
```

Comment: O problema provavelmente não está na copia mas sim no calculo dos primos. Uma forma de fazer um calculo bem rápido dos primos é utilizando o algoritmo de [*Sieve of Eratosthenes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), que é apropriado para calcular primos até um determinado numero limite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essencialmente não. O que provavelmente está deixando lento é a função `primo()`. Precisa ver se o algoritmo é o mais adequado (tem um truque com raiz quadrada), se faz cache de resultados, ou se dá para fazer alguma outra otimização. Achar primos grandes é bem lento porque é exponencial.

Em tese, em certas situações, poderia haver ganho usando alguma biblioteca que manipula a memória com instruções vetorizadas de processadores modernos ou GPU, mas nem sempre é possível usar (esse parece ser um caso que não pode), e é bem avançado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: ola, maneiro, vou editar a pergunta colocando o meu código do número primo

Comment: O problema é que aí virou outra pergunta.